# What's the difference between thread safe and write/read safe?

Tags: ios

In iOS, atomic just guarantee write/read safe. Not thread safe. Someone said thread safe is a higher level. I confuse about their difference. Does w/r safe sometimes could be used to implement thread safe?
And when atomic cannot guarantee
Thread safe. Why we use it in multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

As an example, consider a 64-bit `long` integer type running on a 32-bit processor. Since the processor only operates with 32 bits at a time, updating the `long` looks something like this pseudo-assembly:

```
mov %r1, [addr]
mov %r2, [addr+4]
```

If the variable starts with the value of 0 and you try to write `0xffffffff` to it, then it is possible that execution gets interrupted between these two instructions and other code reading the memory reads the value `0x0000ffff`.

An atomic update guarantees that the entire value is written as a single operation, some way or another, so that while (since it's not thread-safe) you aren't guaranteed exactly when another thread will see an updated value, you *are* guaranteed that whenever it does see a value, it won't be partly updated but will be a completely correct (even if perhaps outdated) value. This concept can be extended to more complex data types where it is relevant.

Comment: So, it can't ensure thread safe. And atomic could be used as a step to implement thread safe. And thread safe is a higher level, we use locks

Answer (score 0):

atomic guarantees exclusive execution only on a single property, that is, you can't read/write a single property on an object at the same time.

However, atomic doesn't guarantee that two different properties of the same object are exclusively accessed/written to at the same time.

The most common example given to illustrate this is a `Person` class with `firstName` and `lastName` properties.

```
let person = Person()

// Thread 1
person.firstName = "Name1"
person.lastName = "LastName1"

// Thread 2
person.firstName = "Name2"
person.lastName = "LastName2"
```

In the worst case, `person` could end up being `Name1 LastName 2` or `Name2 LastName1`.

This is where the higher level thread safety comes into place, I'm using lock/unlock as a placeholder of the platform/language specific locking mechanism.

```
let person = Person()

// Thread 1
lock(person)
person.firstName = "Name1"
person.lastName = "LastName1"
unlock(person)

// Thread 2
lock(person)
person.firstName = "Name2"
person.lastName = "LastName2"
unlock(person)
```

With this locking/unlocking, we guarantee that setting `firstName` and `lastName` on `person` are executed together.

Comment: Yes, from this aspect, thread safe is a higher level about transactions in the program. W/R safe is a common and lower level and doesn&#39;t have a relationship with the logical in our program. Is it right?